# Cannot run python3 script, which uses another package

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run a simple python script on my macOS terminal. The scripts starts with

```
import wfdb #WaveForm-Database package. A library of tools for reading, writing, and processing WFDB signals and annotations.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
```

But it fails with the error `No module named 'wfdb'`which doesn't make sense to me as I just installed the package:

```
user in ~/ecg  > pip3 install wfdb 
Requirement already satisfied: wfdb in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: SoundFile>=0.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (3.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from wfdb) (1.11.4)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (4.46.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (1.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas>=1.3.0->wfdb) (2023.3.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas>=1.3.0->wfdb) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->wfdb) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->wfdb) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->wfdb) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->wfdb) (2023.11.17)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from SoundFile>=0.10.0->wfdb) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0->SoundFile>=0.10.0->wfdb) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=3.2.2->wfdb) (1.16.0)

user in ~/ecg  > python3 convert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/ecg/convert.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wfdb #WaveForm-Database package. A library of tools for reading, writing, and processing WFDB signals and annotations.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wfdb'
```

Comment: What happens if you run `type python3`?

Comment: You've probably got multiple Python versions floating around. Consider `python3 -m pip install wfdb`. This will use the exact Python version referenced by `python3` to install the module

Comment: Try to create new virtualenv and use it

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: I'm guessing that your `python3` and `pip3` commands are referring to different installations of python on your computer.

Comment: Always call the pip module from your desired Python.